# what is the difference between anchor inside button and button inside anchor?

Tags: javascript, html

I trying to understand, how browser parser works.
Here is the code that I am trying to execute:

```
<script>
    function echo_text(){
        alert("helo");
    }
</script>   
<button onclick="echo_text()">
    foo <a href="http://www.google.com">bar</a> zap
</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="http://www.google.com">
    foo <button onclick="echo_text()">bar</button>zap
</a>
```

in both the cases 'alert' is being executed before redirecting.
I am confused in understanding the execution flow, will any one please explain about the flow of execution.

Comment: Nesting an `a` inside of a `button` is syntactically incorrect. They both work because your browser is smart enough to correct the mistake for you.

Comment: some browsers (coughIEcough) used a trickle-down, so a click on the a/button would trigger the `<a>` first, because it was higher up in the DOM tree. other browsers would start from the bottom up, and the click would hit the `<button>` first, then (maybe) bubble upwards to the `<a>`

Comment: alert() blocks execution until the ok button is clicked.

Comment: Thank you All, for your helpful response :)

Answer (score 2):

**Both are illegal**, since `button` and `a` with `href` are both interactive content. And both are not allowed to contain interactive content elements:

> `a` allowed content:
> Transparent, but there must be no interactive content or a element descendants.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-a-element

> `button` allowed content:
> Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-button-element

So end of the story.

---

If browsers allow them, they will probably trigger the `click` event on the deepest element first, and let the event boils up to the rooted element.
Hence, you see the alert in both cases. You won't if you stop the boiling (with a `return false;`? I'm not sure about the exact way to stop boiling).